# valgrind invalid read size

Tags: c, ubuntu

In the valgrind output below, can some explain the meaning of the top line that refrences strlen in a valgrind library.  Does this mean that valgrind itslef has a bug?

```
==26147== Invalid read of size 1
==26147==    at 0x4C2E0E2: strlen (in/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26147==    by 0x40263A: urldecode (server.c:1131)
==26147==    by 0x401853: main (server.c:199)
==26147==  Address 0xffefffaa0 is on thread 1's stack
==26147==  136 bytes below stack pointer

char* urldecode(const char* s)
{
    // check whether s is NULL
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // allocate enough (zeroed) memory for an undecoded copy of s
    char* t = calloc(strlen(s) + 1, 1);  <--- line 1131
```

Comment: You better be looking at `server.c:1131`

Comment: Be cautious of accusing your tools of being buggy. It's usually (but not always) your own code.

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: That looks like a C string that isn't properly terminated. `strlen` operates on the assumption that the string it is passed ends with the null chacacter. If there isn't a null character in the char array, `strlen` goes out of bounds – through no fault of its own.

Comment: not accusing the tool,  just don't understand the output.  I am relatively new to c and the use of valgrind.  I just need explanation of the the first line of output with the strlen and refrence to valgrind

Comment: valgrind provides its own version of strlen(), shadowing the one from libc. That's ok. Invalid read of size 1 probably means urldecode() is called with invalid but non-NULL pointer which happens to point at 0x00.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stack trace. It says that:

- strlen() tried to read 1 byte of memory that it should not do
  (probably it has gone 1 byte past a buffer you have dynamically allocated)
- that strlen() call was called from server.c line 1131, the urldecode() function.
- the urldecode() function was called from server.c line 199

This means there's a bug in your code.
You find the topmost element in the stack trace that is your code, likely this is line 1131 in server.c.

From line 1131 you start figuring out why you're passing an invalid string to strlen(). Perhaps it's a string that uninitialized or not properly nul terminated.

Eventually you might need to track down the place where your string is created, the new code you've posted for the urldecode() function looks fine,  so you might need to go back to server.c line 199 and see how the string you've passed to urldecode() has been made.